# Numba - TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__

Tags: typeerror, jit, numba

I am using Numba with Anaconda and wondering why

```
@jit(argtypes=[int16[:], int16[:]])
def index(ic, nc):
    return ic[0] + nc[0] * (ic[1] + nc[1] * ic[2])
```

does not work:

```
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

But if I use `@autojit` instead of `@jit(..)` everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly confusing from reading the Numba examples, but you actually need to import `int16` from the numba namespace.

The error you are seeing is consistent with importing `int16` from NumPy.  So if at the top of your file, your code looks like:

```
from numba import *
from numpy import *
```

Then you'll accidentally override int16 with the NumPy definition of it.  There are two fixes.  First, you could just swap the order of your imports:

```
from numpy import *
from numba import *
```

Or, more correctly, you could import the namespaces without the * and refer explicitly to what you need:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(argtypes=[nb.int16[:], nb.int16[:]])
```